# what kind of tape is used in electronic devices

Tags: components, sourcing

I repair quite a few devices and one thing that bothers me is that when I remove some of the tape pieces they never go back down right. I was looking for some replacement tape and didn't know what to search for. In the image of a samsung note tablet I highlighted some of the pieces. Is this just a version of capton tape? what should I be searching for on digikey etc. ?

[image: image is from https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Samsung+Galaxy+Note+10.1+Battery+Replacement/30608]

Comment: Use kapton tape, kapton is a wonder material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kapton (polyimide) tape is brown, like the flat flex cables. The tape in the photograph is clearly green and seems to be polyester tape, not polyimide--[powder coating masking tape](http://www.kaptontape.com/Green_Masking_Tapes.php), specifically.

It is similar to Kapton in its mechanical properties (including heat resistance) and uses a similar silicone adhesive, but costs less and has poorer chemical and radiation resistance. No doubt cost was more important than inertness in this application, which must have motivated the choice of polyester tape.

You could certainly use Kapton if you prefer--it depends on your requirements for volume and whatever other applications you might have in mind for it as to which would be more economical.

Answer (score -1):

The answer you gave is correct. The tape is called "Kapton", and is used in many consumer electronics, including this phone. You can read about the tape [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AKapton). Kapton tape is sold on Digikey [here](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/tapes-adhesives/tape/3866785?k=kapton), and it can also be found on many other electronics parts sites for a decent price. [This](http://www.uline.com/Product/Detail/S-14532/High-Temperature-Tapes/Kapton-Tape-1-Mil-1-8-x-36-yds?pricode=WY637&gadtype=pla&id=S-14532&gclid=CjwKEAiAmNW2BRDL4KqS3vmqgUESJABiiwDTlaHmuahrfxqRyZ_Wf_dWcgevgQbw2OEzW2KBUt5YDRoCGcfw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) Kapton tape is sold at 6$ for two rolls. Good luck with your repairs!

EDIT: The tape in the stock devices is not Kapton. Kapton is a suitable replacement of a higher quality but is more expensive. The tape here is powder coating masking tape. You can find it [here](http://www.digikey.com/catalog/en/partgroup/8905-series/27653) on Digikey. I apologize for the misinformation.